# PowerMock + Java + protected Class

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Имеется сторонняя библиотека, spy объект класса которой необходимо. Но единственный конструктор класса protected, принимающий 1 параметр String. Создавать 1 класс наследник для теста, я считаю не корректным. Может кто знает как создать экземпляр данного класса и передать аргумент?

Comment: Непонятно. А разве модификатор `protected` у конструктора запрещает вам создать экземпляр данного класса? Вы пробовали?  http://ideone.com/sexhyT

Comment: Да, просто IDEA ругалась на это, я даже не компилировал. Был уверен, что это не сработает. Но в итоге заработало, что немного странно. Ведь если конструктор prtotected, то нельзя создать экземпляр данного класса из другого. Я всегда думал так.

Comment: Внутри пакета, где определен класс - можно так делать. Но это единственное условие конечно

Comment: Я просто думал default внутри пакета.